# Styling .here class - ul div class

Tags: html, css

Every `ul` with the class `.here` will have these styles.

```
ul.here{
    border-left: solid 2px #c2c2c2;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

However....

I would like the `ul` div `#nav-sub` with the class here to have these styles.

```
ul#nav-sub.here{
    border-left: solid 2px #c2c2c2;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

How do I get this to work ?

Comment: lol, I didn't even recognize that! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess from your description that

```
ul#nav-sub .here
```

could be the right CSS selector, as long as #nav-sub is **unique** as an id on this page.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tesVA/)

Comment: Thanks dude perfect answer - Works - sorry can't vote you up need 11 REP!

Comment: heheh..im late for the answer.by the way. just a jsfiddle to @sebsemillia http://jsfiddle.net/Y7M23/

Comment: @Adam Kolinski glad I could help. But maybe you can give my answer a check mark instead..? ;)

Comment: @Vainglory07 hehe, I was just about to add one myself.. ;) But thx! :)

Comment: There you go CHECK CHECK!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
ul.here{
    border-left: solid 2px #c2c2c2;
    padding-left:5px;
}

ul.here #nav-sub{
    border-left: solid 2px #c2c2c2;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="here">
<li>item</li>
<li><div id="nav-sub">nav-sub</div></li>
</ul>
```